# How do you position mat-datepicker-toggle mat-icon at the end of the date input field

Tags: angular, angular6

I have tried to search all over the net for some time now and no direct answer to this.
I want the toggle icon be placed at the very end of the date input field.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe try the example

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Legend! searched and searched.... phew!

Answer (score 3):

To position the icon at the end you have to use `matSuffix`, and if you want it at the beginning, `matPrefix`.

```
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="rangePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>


  <mat-datepicker-toggle matPrefix [for]="rangePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
```

Comment: Not too late to say thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can make one custom icon that open date picker from click event you can place this button in where you want:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

<button mat-raised-button (click)="picker.open()">Open</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want the icon to be positioned at the end. What You have done is exactly what I am running.